# Validar texbox de 1 al 100

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Estoy haciendo una validacion en la cual pueda registrar numeros de 1 al 100, en cuanto sea mas salga un mensaje de error y lo limpie el texbox, funciona perfecto, cuando el usuario salga de ese texbox le salta el segundo mensaje diciendo de que introdusca el numero puesto q no puede quedar vacio, les muestro el codigo.

```
 <td><input type="number" style="width:45px;" id = "txtNotaDecidir<%:contDecidir %>" min="0" max="100" onblur = "Validar(event, this.id)"  onkeyup = "ValidarNumero(event, this.id)" ng-model="model.selected.<%: eval.ColNota %>" /></td>

 <script type="text/javascript">
       document.addEventListener('keyup', Validar, true);
       function ValidarNumero(nota) {
           var idTexto = document.activeElement.id;
           var num = document.getElementById(idTexto).value;
              if (parseFloat(num) < 0 || parseFloat(num) > 100) {
                   alert("El numero no puede ser mayor a 100");                    
                    document.getElementById(idTexto).focus;
                    return document.getElementById(idTexto).value = "";                                 

               } else
                   return nota.value;                  
       }
      document.addEventListener('onblur', Validar, false);

       function Validar(nota,id) {                    
           var num = document.getElementById(id).value;
               if (num == "") {
                   alert("Introduzca nota");
                   document.getElementById(id).focus;
               }           
           else
               return nota.value;
       }
        </script>
```

Mi pregunta es porque cuando introduzco un numero mayor a 100 me muestra las dos ventanas de error todo el tiempo, no me deja hacer nada por las ventanas, que puede estar mal en el codigo, por favor ayuda...

Comment: Si estás realmente trabajando con MVC, entonces bastará con agregar `[Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Debe ser entre 1 y 100.")]` en tu modelo, sobre la propiedad que deseas.

Comment: Te recomiendo que empieces por sacar las propiedades `onblur` y `onkeyup` del input ya que estas agregando los Listener abajo

Answer (score 1):

se supone que estás trabajando con el patrón MVC (Modelo-Vista-Controlador), por lo tanto, debes aplicar la validación directamente en el modelo para que este se refleje en tu página:

```
public class Movie {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Rating { get; set; }
}
```

Para tu caso, el campo Price aplica la validación de rangos. Aclarando, que esta validación ocurrirá cuando se envíe el formulario/control.

Ahora bien, si lo que deseas es validarlo desde el cliente necesitas las librerías de JQuery:

- jquery.validate.js
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Y luego debes agregar a tus controles los siguientes atributos:

- data-val-range="Los valores deben estar dentro del rango..."
- data-val-range-max="VALOR MAXIMO"
- data-val-range-min="VALOR MINIMO"

Quedaría algo como esto:

```
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" data-val="true" data-val-range="Mensaje de error aquí" data-val-range-max="100" data-val-range-min="1"/>
```